# What is the length of session variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, session-variables

I'm trying to store a query into a variable (@sqlstmt) in a stored procedure, but its taking only 1024 characters and truncating the query.

How should I change the size of session variable ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using GROUP_CONCAT by any chance?

Comment: Have a sample of your query and maybe even the whole sql script you are using?

Comment: SET sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT('max(case when col1 = ''',col1,''' then col2 end) AS ', col1)) INTO sql FROM yourtable;

    SET sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', sql, 'FROM yourtable GROUP BY id');

    PREPARE stmt FROM sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Comment: for the above please replace sql with @sql, the comment section was not allowing me to use tht multiple times.

Comment: @Zzyrk yes im using GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024.

To set it to a higher value :

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = yourValue;
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)